# jQuery: fading in modal dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog, fade

is it possible to smoothly fadein a jquery modal dialog? (can't find anything in the docs).
i've tried fadeTo but didn't help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [`show` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-show) (admittedly not well named, too general), like this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ show: 'fade' });
```

The close animation is the matching [`hide` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-hide), for example:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ show: 'fade', hide: 'drop' });
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/DntpH/)

Comment: works in your demo but not with me :/
need to figure out what's wrong - thanks anyway!

Comment: @Fuxi - Which version of jQuery UI are you using? `fade` was added as an effect in 1.8, won't work in prior versions.

Comment: yep i had an old version - just updated jquery to 1.42 and ui to 1.84 - still same problem :/
works nice when using: me.dialog("open");
but not with: me.dialog({ show: 'fade' });
when using fade simply nothing will happen..

Comment: @Fuxi - Any errors in your console? Keep in mind that my answer is about the *setup*, not the open call.  For instance, if you have `autoOpen: false` you still need to call `.dialog('open')`, and the `show` option should be in your setup options, for example: `.dialog({ autoOpen: false, show: 'fade' })` then later `.dialog('open')`.

Comment: thx - that was the problem :) i put it in the options, it shows up - but now next problem: it's not fading in but folding in! the dialog is also plain white (no header bar, no content)

Comment: @Fuxi - very odd, do you have a link to a page I can see the behavior in?

Answer (score 3):

You could define `show` and `hide` as objects which will give you access to more options:

```
$("#element").dialog({
    show: {
        effect: 'fade',
        duration: 200 //at your convenience
    },
    hide: {
        effect: 'fade',
        duration: 200 //at your convenience
    }
});
```

Comment: this should be chosen answer!